# How I can access latest prerelease nuget version

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package, cicd, branching-and-merging

I have a following nuget packages
Test.1.0.0.1.nupkg
Test.1.0.0.2-rc1.nupkg
Test.1.0.0.3-rc1.nupkg
Test.1.0.0.4.nupkg
Test.1.0.0.3-beta1.nupkg

I want to install the latest prerelease  package based on branch input. So if user pass rc1 then it should install Test.1.0.0.3-rc1.nupkg

I tried
Nugget install Test - version "*-rc1" but it gives error invalid version string.